# Compare the string with other string using regular expression in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an input string "xyz" to function either in upper or lower case.

In this, I have to compare against the string "test|xyz|test1|xyz1". if it found, I have to return 'Y'. 
Is there any in built function or regular expression  available to perform this check in oracle.

Comment: Do you have `test|xyz|test1|xyz1` in a table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Select 'Y' from dual where regexp_like('test|xyz|test1|xyz1','xyz','i');
```

It will return result only for matched values. If you want 'n' for unmatched values then try regular expression instring.

Or you can do it simply with lower() function on both side and checking for instring.

```
select case when 
       regexp_instr('test|xyz|test1|xyz1','XYz',1,1,1,'i') > 0 then 'y'
       else 'n' end col1 
from dual
```

Comment: @user2750658, are u sure this is what you need? this will match `xyz` with `test|test1|xyz1` also.